# Netbeans 11.2 libraries

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-11

I've installed netbeans 11.2. Now I want to start a new project, and I need to add some libraries. In previous versions. In project properties there was a folder with libraries. Now I don't see where I can add them.

[image: Project properties]

Any help?

Comment: This is nothing to do with NetBeans 11.2. You have a Maven project and NetBeans never has provided a _Libraries_ property for Maven projects. Instead, specify your dependencies in **pom.xml**. See [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a Maven project which does not have that "Libraries" page in the project settings.

If you want to add a Maven dependency, you can right click on the "Dependencies" node of your project and choose "Add dependency":

[image]

Then you can search for the library you want in Maven central.

If you didn't want to create Maven project, but want to use an Ant based project (the "native" project type in NetBeans), you will have to delete your Maven project and create a new one, and select  "Java with Ant" as the project's category:

[image]

once you have done that, you'll have your "Libraries" sheet back in the project properties.